# How to access a property of an item in a view when item is provided by observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, observable

I have the following provider code :

```
  getWorldCities2() {
    return this.http.get('../assets/city.list.json')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

The page typescript code :

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getWorldCities();
  }

  getWorldCities(){
    this.AppCitiesProvider.getWorldCities2()
    .subscribe(
        (cities) => {
            this.worldCities = cities;
            this.firstCity = cities[0].name;
            console.log(this.worldCities);
            this.generateGrid();
        },
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    ;
  }
  generateGrid(){
    let plusCity = new City();
    this.favoriteCities.push(plusCity);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.favoriteCities.length; i+=2) { //iterate images
      this.grid[rowNum] = Array(2); //declare two elements per row
      if (this.favoriteCities[i]) { //check file URI exists
        this.grid[rowNum][0] = {name:this.favoriteCities[i].name , id:this.favoriteCities[i].id,
      country:this.favoriteCities[i].country, coord:this.favoriteCities[i].coord
    };
        console.log(this.grid[rowNum][0]);
      }
      if (this.favoriteCities[i+1]) { //repeat for the second image
         this.grid[rowNum][1] = this.favoriteCities[i+1]
      }
      rowNum++; //go on to the next row
     }
  }
```

And my html page hase that :

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let row of grid">
    <ion-col width-50 *ngFor="let city of row">
    {{city}}
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

That works well in the sense that I don't get any error, the page displays [object Object].

So when the observable sends the response, it goes though and everything resolves itself.

The issue is when I replace {{city}} with {{city.name}} . 
I get a 
Cannot find property name of 'undefined'.

My guess is that the view is trying to resolve city.name before the observable has set the data.

What should be the correct way to tell the view to "wait" ?

Thanks

Comment: Try `{{city | json}}` to see what the content of `city` looks like.

Comment: Please see below. But the issue is not that "name" would be undefined, rather the city itself... Which obviously is not the case, as we get this object
    {
  "name": "plus",
  "id": 0,
  "country": null
}

Comment: It's still worth a try. Your conclusion that Angular renders before data is available does not hold, at least not if there are no async calls in `generateGrid`. `*ngFor` doesn't render rows before they are there.

Comment: Why is it doing it here obviously ?

Comment: It isn't, but it's hard for me to find the real reason without a reproduction.

Comment: What can I do to help ?

Comment: create a reproduction in stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

you access to an observable value in the view without subscribing to it by using async Pipe:

```
{{ myObservable | async}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Async be 'async' in lowercase? https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe